# correct typing of indexById function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to implement `indexById` function which can take `Array` of objects. Each object will have unique `id` property and may have different `value` property.

Expected output will be an `object` where keys will be the `id` from the value and value will be the object in array, example below.

The input array is passed directly to the function or marked as `const`

Writing javascript logic for this is straightforward. But how to make the outout typesafe?

```js
output = getIndexById([
    {
        id: '1',
        value: 'abc'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        value: 123
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        value: {someProp: 3}
    }
])
  
//expected output
const output = {
    '1': {
        id: '1',
        value: 'abc'
    },
    '2': {
        id: '2',
        value: 123
    },
    '3': {
        id: '3',
        value: {someProp: 3}
    }
}

output.3.value.someProp // typescript should know this is number
```

Comment: I did not understand the exact requirement. what does this statement means `Expected output will be an object where keys will be the id from the value and value will be the object in array` . Can you please explain it in more better way ?

Comment: It's possible if the ID is always the same as the array index. But I don't think there's a way to do it otherwise, since there's no way to know the ID really is unique.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```
const output = getIndexById([
    {
        id: '1',
        value: 'abc'
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        value: 123
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        value: {someProp: 3}
    }
] as const)

// type: 3
const three = output['3'].value.someProp

type IdObj = { id: string }
type IdArray = ReadonlyArray<IdObj>
type ById<A, O extends Record<string, IdObj>> = 
  A extends readonly [infer H extends IdObj, ...infer T extends IdArray] 
    ? ById<T, O & Record<H['id'], H>> 
    : O

function getIndexById<T extends IdArray>(arr: T): ById<T, {}> {
  throw new Error("unimplemented")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define interfaces and pass the expected `types` as `generic` in the  `outputObject`

```
interface dynamicObject {
    [k: string]: any
}
interface inputArray<T> {
  id: string;
  value: T;
}
interface outputObject {
  [k: string]: inputArray<string|number|dynamicObject>;
}
const getIndexById = (): outputObject => {
  return {
    '1': {
      id: '1',
      value: 'abc',
    },
    '2': {
      id: '2',
      value: 123,
    },
    '3': {
      id: '3',
      value: { someProp: 3 },
    },
  };
};
```